# Changing Updating Frequency of CMAltimeter

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nstimer, cmaltimeter

I am working on an app that uses the CMAltimeter class. I would like to retrieve altitude values quicker than the default value (default seems to be about once every second). How can I change the frequency? Will I need to use NSTimers/Multiple instances? If so, an explanation would be much appreciated.

```
if ([CMAltimeter isRelativeAltitudeAvailable])
{
    self.altimeterManager = [[CMAltimeter alloc] init];
    [self.altimeterManager startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAltitudeData *altitudeData, NSError *error)
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
             NSLog(@"%f", altitudeData.relativeAltitude.floatValue);
         });
     }];
}
```

Comment: There's API to set the frequency. The docs simply state "Core Motion generates events at regular intervals", whatever that happens to be.

Comment: does this mean I will be able to change this frequency?

Comment: Oops. I meant to type "There's **no** API to set the frequency". So no, you can't change it.